# How do I add the SEM for multiple groups in a column plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to this site and programming in general so if this is a repeat question, I apologize. So here is the code:

```
dataset %>% group_by(factor) %>%
  summarise(`variable`= mean(`variable`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor, `variable`)) +
  geom_col(aes(fct_relevel(factor, "level", after=4L)))
```

For simplicity, I just replaced the factor variable and level names with the corresponding column type. I just need to know how to add the SEM to this plot. Thanks!

Comment: I assume with *SEM* you mean *standard error of the mean*. I'd regard it as bad practice to plot mean + se with bars. You could try `stat_summary` instead.

Comment: In my field (neuroscience) it is common place for figures in publications to have the mean+sem on a column graph.

Comment: General advise: In case an answer is helpful, you may accept and/or up vote it. In case the answer isn't sufficient, you could comment what is missing, so that the answer may be improved.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mean_se` from `ggplot2` here. This computes the mean and the standard error for us. Since the output is a `data.frame`, we must wrap it within a `list`, which we can unnest with `tidyr::unnest`. After that plotting proceeds as normal.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
# or simply use `library(tidyverse)`

theme_set(theme_bw())


pdata <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(new = list(mean_se(Sepal.Length))) %>% 
  unnest(new)


pdata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species, y)) +
  geom_col(width = .5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))
```

[image]

If you want the order of factors, I would supply the variable only once. You can put all mappings to variables into the first call to `aes` too:

```r
pdata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fct_relevel(Species, "versicolor"), y, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_col(width = .5) +
  geom_errorbar()
```

---

In general I'd recommend plotting points and error bars though, since they use a lot less ink, and you can see more clearly what is going on.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary()
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()
```

[image]